# Limits for AWS Batch job details retention

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I'm trying to understand how long the details associated with an AWS Batch job are retained. For example, the [Kinesis limits page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html) describes how each stream defaults to a 24 hour retention period that is extendable up to 7 days.

The AWS [Batch limits page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/service_limits.html) does not include any details about either the maximum time or count allowed for jobs. It does say that one million is the limit for SUBMITTED jobs, but its unclear if that is exclusively for SUBMITTED or includes other states as well.

Does anybody know the details of batch job retention?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Job metadata for SUCCEEDED and FAILED jobs are retained for 24 hours.  Metadata for Jobs in SUBMITTED, PENDING, RUNNABLE, STARTING, and RUNNING remain in the queue until the job completes. Your AWS Batch Jobs also log STDERR/STDOUT to CloudWatch Logs where you control the retention policy.

Comment: Source of this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_user.pdf

Answer (score 0):

From AWS Batch official doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_user.pdf

Under Jobs -> Job States ([Page 23](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_user.pdf#page=23))

> `FAILED`
>
> The job has failed all available attempts. The job state for `FAILED` jobs is persisted in AWS Batch for at least 24 hours.
>
> **Note**
>
> Logs for `FAILED` jobs are available in CloudWatch Logs; the log group is /aws/batch/job, and the log stream name format is *first200CharsOfJobDefinitionName*/default/*ecs_task_id* (this format may change in the future). After a job reaches the `RUNNING` status, you can programmatically retrieve its log stream with the [DescribeJobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobs.html) API operation. For more information, see [View Log Data Sent to CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#ViewingLogData) in the Amazon CloudWatch Logs User Guide. By default, these logs are set to never expire, but you can modify the retention period. For more information, see [Change Log Data Retention in CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) in the *Amazon CloudWatch Logs User Guide*.

Comment: It is not obvious what additional insight this post provides. Please explain the difference to the information provided by the existing answer. A screenshot of text is less useful thatn the textual summary provided in the existing answer. If the screenshot you provieded has any useful additional information, that needs to be highlighted and ideally typed instead being part of a picture of text. Try to avoid the impression that you provide no additional information beyond the accepted and upvoted existing answer - and in a less helpful way.

Comment: It explains about actual source of this retention. Screenshot was added for those who want to read the main information instead of scanning the entire doc. Additionally If you have 1000s of AWS batch jobs it will be hard to scan cloudwatch to retrieve information about just one AWS batch job. There is no mapping available between AWS Batch job id and cloudwatch log stream id. This provides a way to get mapping information using describeJob API which can be stored at user end.

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] to add that info to the answer itself.